# Gcloud DNS: Couldn't load discovery

Tags: dns, gcloud

after updating gcloud components (gcloud components update) I get an error when trying to list my gcloud DNS zones. I can perform all changes from the web gui, but not from command line.

I'm doing this:

```
gcloud config set account myaccount
gcloud config set project myproject
gcloud dns managed-zone list
```

And I get:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.dns.managed-zone.list) Couldn't load discovery
```

I've been using this for some months without any problems until today. Any suggestions?

Edit: As suggested, it seemed some problem on Google's side. It's now working again as expected.

Answer (score -1):

Having the same issue, I believe they are having some type of outage.

Edit: I would post this as a comment but I don't have the "rep"....

Edit: It now appears to be fixed.